# Fatorial com múltiplas entradas em Python

Tags: python

Preciso escrever um programa na linguagem Python que leia múltiplas entradas, e que, ao receber a entrada "-1", o programa imprima os fatoriais dos respectivos números da entrada.

Detalhe: preciso utilizar a função laço `while`, já que faz parte do assunto atual que estudo. Estou escrevendo da seguinte maneira:

```
while True:
    n = int(raw_input())
    if n >= 0:
        continue
    if n == -1:
        break
    numeroCalc = n
    fatorial = 1
    while numeroCalc > 0:
        fatorial = fatorial * numeroCalc
        numeroCalc = numeroCalc - 1
    print fatorial
```

Mas não está funcionando.

Comment: O que não está funcionando? Pode usar uma lista ou algo assim?

Comment: O programa não imprime os Fatoriais... O programa encerra após a entrada "-1", e não imprime os fatoriais.

Comment: Acredito que possa sim usar uma lista, contanto que use a função while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pelo que você disse querem, deve ser +/- assim o código

```
numb = "\n"

while True:
    n = int(raw_input())
    if n == -1:
        break
    numeroCalc = n
    fatorial = 1
    while numeroCalc > 0:
        fatorial = fatorial * numeroCalc
        numeroCalc = numeroCalc - 1
    numb = numb+str(fatorial)+"\n"

print numb
```

Comment: Então devo apenas retirar o continue e manter o break?

Comment: Ao retirar o continue, o programa imprime o fatorial logo após a entrada, e não é assim que deve ser. Eu devo pôr mais de uma entrada, e o programa deve lê-las, e só deve imprimir os fatoriais de cada entrada após a entrada "-1", que representa: acabei, imprima os fatoriais de cada entrada, cada um em uma linha. Obrigado pela atenção :D

Comment: acho q entendi, tenta o código que coloquei

Comment: Funciona, mas não posso utilizar pois possui termos que ainda não foram abordados nas aulas que assisti... como n.append() e del().

Comment: isso deve resolver

Comment: Funciona! :D Agora só tenho que entender kkk mas parece simples, muito obrigado!